# SpringBoot Health Response Difference

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

I have 2 same structured SpringBoot(version=2.4.8) applications. I am using Spring Boot actuator lib for health checks. I set 2 properties(in application.properties) as below for both applications;

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

When I call /actuator/health endpoint for both it is working but responding with different structure

Application A is like :

```json
{
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "details": {
        "database": "Oracle",
        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
      },
      "status": {
        "code": "UP",
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "details": {
        "total": 16095641600,
        "free": 11911487488,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "exists": true
      },
      "status": {
        "code": "UP",
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "details": {},
      "status": {
        "code": "UP",
        "description": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "status": {
    "code": "UP",
    "description": ""
  },
  "groups": []
}
```

Application B is like :

```json
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "components": {
        "logDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Oracle",
            "validationQuery": "isValid()"
          }
        },
        "primaryDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Oracle",
            "validationQuery": "isValid()"
          }
        },
        "tkfqlogDS": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "database": "Oracle",
            "validationQuery": "isValid()"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 16095641600,
        "free": 11911487488,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

Why is it different despite the same Spring Boot version and the same configuration?

ApplicationA pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApplicationA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApplicationA</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <couchbase.client.version>2.6.2</couchbase.client.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalOptions>
                        <additionalOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOption>
                    </additionalOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${couchbase.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.paluch.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

ApplicationB pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApplicationB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.21-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApplicationB</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <couchbase.client.version>2.6.2</couchbase.client.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalOptions>
                        <additionalOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOption>
                    </additionalOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${couchbase.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.paluch.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share `pom.xml` of both applications? Thanks!

Comment: sure but how can attach it, since both are a little bit long files

Comment: You can't, you have to inline them, just like you did with the JSON.

Comment: You can find pom.xml contents

Answer (score 0):

The difference seems to be related with the following dependency that is available in `ApplicationB` but not in `ApplicationA`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This makes me wonder how you are running ApplicationA.

Comment: Thanks for your response @João, ApplicationA is doing just batch jobs, nothing more but ApplicationB carries rest apis

Comment: Then I bet this dependency is the reason for the differences. I've been looking into the source code to find proofs but it is rather hard to find them.